# Create my own sidebarPane in my panel not in elements or sources panel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

`chrome.devtools.elements.createSideBarPane` allows creating a sidebarpane in the elements panel.

But how do I create a sidebarpane for MY custom panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how the console works, let me clarify it to you: the `elements.createSidebarPane` method will only create sidebar panes in the Elements panel. If you create a **custom Panel**, with your own HTML code and stuff, then **you'll need to create your Sidebar Pane by yourself**, simply adding it into your Panel's HTML code, and styling it to be shown on the right side of the console, like a normal Pane.

Comment: I knew that just wanted to clarify. Thanks